# Spark Python: sortBy causes ValueError: Unicode float() literal too long to convert

Tags: python, apache-spark, unicode, pyspark, hadoop2

I have a RDD looking like this:

```
rdd.take(2)
```

*(ID, avg rating)*

> [(u'1269', 433355525.39999998), (u'1524', 5693044.25)] ...

I am trying to sort it by function `sortBy()`

```
sorted = rdd.sortBy(lambda x: x[1])
```

It should return sorted list of IDs. I'm getting the following error instead:

> ValueError: Unicode float() literal too long to convert

```
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
```

I tired to do convert the float value back to Unicode, and backwards. I tried to round it etc.

> [(u'1269', 433355525.0), (u'1524', 5693044.0)]

Maybe using a Decimal would be solution, but I'm using Python 2.6.6 and it seems to me it is overkill anyway.

Spark 1.6.3.

How can I fix this?

Added simple code:

`lines = sc.textFile("/user/ahouskova/movies/my.data")
columns_data = lines.map(lambda line: line.split("\t"))
ratings = columns_data.map(lambda c: (c[1], (c[2], 1.0)))
movie_ratings_total_counts = ratings.reduceByKey(lambda m1, m2: (m1[0] + m2[0], m1[1] + m2[1]))
avg_ratings = movie_ratings_total_counts.mapValues(lambda total: round(float(total[0])/total[1]))
sorted_by_avg_rtg = avg_ratings.sortBy(lambda x: x[1])`

rounded

> [(u'1269', '433355525.0'), (u'1524', '5693044.0')]

string formatted

> [(u'1269', '433355525.400'), (u'1524', '5693044.250')]

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the new data you provided about the code you are running.

The error your provided is: *ValueError: Unicode float() literal too long to convert*

The problem seems to be:

- reading string
- splitting it by "\t" (note: it is still a string)
- **perform `reduceByKey` assuming that the second element is a float 
  while it is actually a string.**

**You can cast the second element to float** in this line:

Instead of:

```
ratings = columns_data.map(lambda c: (c[1], (c[2], 1.0)))
```

You can do:

```
ratings = columns_data.map(lambda c: (c[1], (float(c[2]), 1.0)))
```

Comment: Hello. Ive tried convert it even during computing that float. Your conversion map function shows the same error as I mentioned above.

Comment: @la_femme_it - the meaning of the failure in the `map` function, is that the RDD which you `map`, has invalid data in the second element of the one (or more) tuples.

Comment: @la_femme_it There is no enough data in your question which will allow us to understand what is the source of the problem (can be the input data, the calculation of the 2nd element of the tuple - i.e. the avg, or something else)

Comment: @la_femme_it - I've updated my answer. You should convert the 2nd element of the tuple to float, e.g. using `ratings = columns_data.map(lambda c: (c[1], (float(c[2]), 1.0))) `

Comment: @la_femme_it - did I answer your question?

Comment: Casting to float right during the mapping helped. Thx.

Comment: @la_femme_it - happy to help :)